# How do i use Xbox 360 controller with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, xbox360

This code goes into infinite loop. I cant use A button on xbox 360 controller

```
import pygame
from pygame import joystick


pygame.init()


joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)


pygame.joystick.init()

print("start")
while True:

    if joystick.get_button(0) == 1  :
        print("stoped")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cant use A button on xbox 360 controller

Personnaly, I can, so this seems to be possible. You are just missing that pretty much every user input needs to be updated by pygame through `pygame.event.get()`.

From the [pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html#pygame.joystick.Joystick):

> Once the device is initialized the pygame event queue will start receiving events about its input.

So, apparently you need to get the events in the `while` loop [like such](https://riptutorial.com/pygame/example/18046/event-loop) to make the joystick work:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # get the events (update the joystick)
        if event.type == QUIT: # allow to click on the X button to close the window
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    if joystick.get_button(0):
        print("stopped")
        break
```

---

Also,

1. In the line `if joystick.get_button(0) == 1`, you don't need to type  `== 1` because the statement is already `True`.
2. You are initializing `pygame.joystick` twice: through the line `pygame.init()` and `pygame.joystick.init()`.
3. You don't need to type `from pygame import joystick` because you already already have it in the line `import pygame`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take this as reference and use it in your own way.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WIDTH,HEIGHT = 500,500
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLUISH = (75,75,255)
YELLOW =(255,255,0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

smile = pygame.image.load("smile.jpg")
smile = pygame.transform.scale(smile,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))

idle = pygame.image.load("idle.jpg")
idle = pygame.transform.scale(idle,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))

joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(x) for x in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
    
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif  event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            if  event.button == 0: #press A button to smile
                screen.fill(WHITE)
                screen.blit(smile,(0,0))
                pygame.display.update()
                clock.tick(10)
        elif  event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            if  event.button == 0:
                screen.fill(WHITE)
                screen.blit(idle,(0,0))
                pygame.display.update()
                clock.tick(10)
```

[image: Button Reference]

Comment: ummm how am I supposed to find the images? This is not a MRE.

Comment: @D_00 you can use whatever images you want, the answer is about how to process game pad button events.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point out that your code could be updated in such a way that you don't need the images to run it, in order to make it what is called a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)